# .NET WinForms: How to use an API call that requires a window handle?

Tags: .net, winforms, pinvoke

### Short version

How do i use an API call when i cannot guarantee that the window 
handle will remain valid?

i can guarantee that i'm holding a reference to my form (so the form is not being disposed). That doesn't guarantee that the form's **handle** will stay valid all that time.

*How can a form's window handle become invalid even though the form is not diposed*?

Because the form's underlying Windows window was destroyed and recreated.

### Long Version

i want to P/Invoke an API that requires a hwnd (a handle to a window). Some examples of API calls that requie an hWnd are:

[IVMRWindowlessControl::SetVideoClippingWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms787175(VS.85).aspx)

```
 HRESULT SetVideoClippingWindow(
    HWND  hwnd
 );
```

[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx)

```
SendMessage(          
   HWND hWnd,
   UINT Msg,
   WPARAM wParam,
   LPARAM lParam
);
```

[SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052.aspx)

```
HWND SetClipboardViewer(
   HWND hWndNewViewer
);
```

[SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx)

```
UINT_PTR SetTimer(
   HWND hWnd,
   UINT_PTR nIDEvent,
   UINT uElapse,
   TIMERPROC lpTimerFunc
);
```

[IProgressDialog::StartProgressDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775262(VS.85).aspx)

```
HRESULT StartProgressDialog(          
   HWND hwndParent,
   IUnknown *punkEnableModless,
   DWORD dwFlags,
   LPCVOID pvReserved
);
```

[Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx)

```
BOOL Shell_NotifyIcon(          
   DWORD dwMessage,
   PNOTIFYICONDATA lpdata  //<--hWnd in there
);
```

[AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632669.aspx)

```
BOOL AnimateWindow(   
   HWND hwnd,
   DWORD dwTime,
   DWORD dwFlags
);
```

**Note:** Some of these API calls have managed equivalents, some do not - but that fact is irrelavent for my question.

### Explanation

i can call one of these API functions, which requires long term window handle, e.g.:

```
private void TellTheGuyToDoTheThing()
{
   SendMessage(this.Handle, 
      WM_MyCustomMessage, 
      paramOneForTheThing, 
      paramTwoForTheThing);
}
```

It has been suggested that the above call to SendMessage is dangerous because of the unmanaged use of a window handle. They suggest that you wrap the hwnd in a HandleRef object:

```
private void TellTheGuyToDoTheThing()
{
   SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle),
      WM_MyCustomMessage, 
      paramOneForTheThing, paramTwoForTheThing);
```

This way: the window handle is guaranteed to stay valid during the call to SendMessage. But it doesn't always work out that way. The following API call requires long-term access to a window handle:

```
private void RegisterWithTheThing()
{
   this.nextClipboardViewerInChain = SetClipboardViewer(
       new HandleRef(this, this.Handle));
}
```

Even though i wrapped the handle in a HandleRef, it is still possible (in the subsequest seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, or years) for the form's window handle to become invalid. This happens when the form's underlying Windows window is destroyed and a new one created. This, despite the fact that i protected the form's handle in a HandleRef.

i can name *one* way in which a form's handle becomes invalid:

```
this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

The form's window is re-created and old hwnd is now invalid.

So the question is: How to use an API call that requires a window handle?

### Cannot be done?

i anticipate the answer: *you cannot do this. There is nothing that can be done to protect the form's handle to ensure it is valid as long as you need to keep the handle.*

This then means that i need to know when the handle is being destroyed, so i can tell Windows to let it go, e.g.:

```
protected override void TheHandleIsAboutToBeDestroyed()
{
    ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, this.nextClipboardViewerInChain);
}
```

and then be told when the new handle is created:

```
protected override void TheHandleWasJustCreated()
{
   RegisterTheThing();
}
```

Except no such ancestor methods exist.

**Alternate question:** Are there methods i can override so i know when a window's handle is about to be destroyed, and when it has just been creatd?

Having to break the .NET WinForms encapsulation of re-creating handles is ugly, but is it the only way?

---

### Update One

Handling the **Close**/**OnClose** event of a form is insufficient, the same goes for

- handling IDisposable
- GC pinning the form

since i can make the form's underlying window handle invalid without closing or disposing form. e.g:

```
private void InvalidThisFormsWindowHandleForFun()
{
   this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
}
```

**Note:** You *destroy* a Windows window handle, you don't dispose of it. Objects in .NET are the things that get disposed of; which, if it's a Form object, will most likely involve *destroying* the Windows window handle.

Windows is a product by Microsoft.

A window is a thing with a message loop and can sometimes show stuff on screen.

---

### Update Two

[me.yahoo.com/a/BrYwg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359763/net-winforms-how-to-use-an-api-call-that-requires-a-window-handle#360023) had a good suggestion for the use of a [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) object to act as a listener for items that require an hWnd which are used to listen for messages. This can be used to solve some issues, like:

- SetClipboardViewer
- SetTimer
- IProgressDialgo::StartProgressDialog
- Shell_NotifyIcon

but doesn't work for

- AnimateWindow
- SendMessage
- IVMRWindowlessControl::SetVideoClippingWindow

Comment: "Windows is a product by Microsoft."  That's not a polite way to thank people who've read your essay to the bottom and may have been thinking about making helpful suggestions.   If you want to abuse a particular responder, why not do it in the comments of his response?

Comment: What in gods name are you talking about? i was clarifying my usage of "Windows" and "windows".

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the functionality in the NativeWindow class?

Comment: i'd never heard of this class. It looks like it's not a visual thinb, but as a non-visual window that can be used to receive messages. This might be good for solving problems (SetClipboardViewer) where i need an hWnd that can recieve messages, but doesn't solve the larger issue.

Comment: Updated original question to include this suggestion as solution for some cases - perhaps it might even be preferable to have a non-visual window as the listener for messages - rather than using a visual form.

Comment: The sample code for NativeWindow involves overriding the OnHandleCreated and OnHandleDestroyed events, as mentioned by slimCODE, and that is what had caught my eye.

Comment: Yeah, i see that now too - which makes me think it doesn't do anything. i thought it was the .net framework equivalent of a helper that was available in another language. i thought it creates a window for you, where you can override the window proc, and use it to receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

Could you live with overriding the OnHandleCreated and OnHandleDestroyed on your form, and act accordingly?

Comment: That might just be the answer i need. After i've tested it i'll vote the answer one way or the other

Answer (score 0):

I think that the form's OnClose function (or related event) should be overriden.

Alternative - each form implements IDisposable - why don't you add code to the Dispose method of the form that belong to that handle.

Comment: Because the handle can be destroyed while the form still exists (i.e. it's never disposed)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a GCHandle for this (System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle).  A GCHandle can be used to "pin" an object so that .NET keeps it in one memory location.  I use this extensively for interacting with the waveOut API; without pinning, the app just mysteriously crashes once in a while.

Obviously this wouldn't be useful in a situation where the window is actually destroyed and then re-created.

Answer (score 0):

> i can name one way in which a form's
>   handle becomes invalid:
>
> ```
> this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
> ```

I know another way:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```